# out of zone data BIND problem

Tags: bind

```
root@server [~]# named-checkzone /var/named/116.64.xxx.in-addr.arpa /var/named/116.64.xxx.db
dns_master_load: /var/named/116.64.xxx.db:2: ignoring out-of-zone data (116.64.xxx.in-addr.arpa)
zone /var/named/116.64.xxx.in-addr.arpa/IN: has 0 SOA records
zone /var/named/116.64.xxx.in-addr.arpa/IN: has no NS records


$TTL 86400
116.64.xxx.in-addr.arpa. IN      SOA     ns1.domain.com. noc.domain.com. (
                                2011041002      ; Serial
                                7200 ; Refresh
                                7200 ; Retry
                                1209600 ; Expire 2 weeks
                                86400 ) ; Minimum 24 hours

                IN      NS      ns1.domain.com.
                IN      NS      ns2.domain.com.
```

IPS directly allocated to me via ARIN.

Using BIND on a cPanel Box / Centos 5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

@      IN      SOA     ns1.domain.com. noc.domain.com. (

Instead of

116.64.xxx.in-addr.arpa. IN      SOA     ns1.domain.com. noc.domain.com. (

Comment: its already like that:
116.64.xxx.in-addr.arpa.         IN      SOA     ns1.domain.com. noc.domain.com. (

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to `named-checkzone` is documented to be the zone name thus should not begin with `/var/named`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
named-checkzone /var/named/116.64.xxx.in-addr.arpa /var/named/116.64.xxx.db
```

Try this instead:

```
named-checkzone 116.64.xxx.in-addr.arpa /var/named/116.64.xxx.db
```

Comment: Strange
'code'
root@server [/var/named]# named-checkzone 116.64.xxx.in-addr.arpa /var/named/116.64.xxx.db    
zone 116.64.xxx.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 2011041002
OK'code'

However, the rdns is showing up as servfail when I run a check.

Comment: What check are you running?  A cut and paste (with xxx replaced and one PTR added) worked for me locally.  `dig +short @0 -x 99.64.116.1`
 returned `test.domain.com.`

Answer (score 0):

Remember to update your serials !

Comment: I have done that for sure, each time.